# Zipping and downloading multiple files

Tags: performance, web-services, memory

We're currently designing an web application that will basically expose "messages" to end users, each message consisting of a subject and body, but more important 1 to many files we call "attachments". This could really be from 1 to possibly 10.000 attachments per message, with attachments being mostly "documents": pdf, xls, csv,.... Still the final zip can quickly grow to >100MB

When the user will consult a specific message, they will have the possibility to either download each attachment 1 by 1, either click a "zip and download" button. We base our developements on webservices, so the "zip and download" will call an endpoint, and this will trigger the retrieval of the files (these attachments are not stored in a classic filesystem but in Documentum) the zipping action and eventually the response.

We're now confronted basically with 2 choices:

**OPTION 1: Do everything in memory**

We can indeed do the whole process without having any file written physically in the file system: request documentum, get the files as bytes (actually base64-encoded string in the response, but that's another story), create a ZIP archive in memory out of these files, then return the bytes from the zip archive as an http response with proper content-disposition and content-type

**OPTION 2: Use the good old filesystem**

Create a physical version of the zip file on some file server and respond to the initial request with a "redirect" response to the physical location of the file (well, actually the URL pointing to a physical location on the fileserver)

---

My feeling is that option 1 could/will quickly cause performance or memory issues (we're using .NET on IIS server for what it's worth), while option 2 without proper cleaning could quickly lead to a full drive, and also offer some kind of temporary access to a file whereas it's much harder to get this file out of the memory if we use option 1.

My question is: what would be the best-practice? Are there other alternatives as such that would be even more suitable?

Comment: I'm presuming that you have no option to change the design of this.  I'm pretty sure I built a streaming solution for this at some point or another with Java using a ZipOutputStream.  I'm not sure whether a corresponding class/utility exists in .NET.  That eliminates the need to build something in memory.  IIRC there were some weird things about doing it this way but it worked.

Comment: Why is this either/or? Surely you could find a caching strategy that lets you read common zips straight from disk without having to recompress?

Comment: An LRU cache could help if people frequently download the same message twice, eg. from multiple devices. Disks are slow, but repeatedly zipping is likely slower.

Comment: @JimmyJames > Seems like we should head to that direction, I will have a look how this can be achieved in .NET

Comment: @AlexReinking > You're right, it could be a "and", but still my main issue is with the memory buffering when returning the file to the user, so I should probably look into  streaming. Then caching is just an improvement in order not to generate the same zip file too often